# Replace duplicates char in string with '_'

Tags: haskell, replace

I'm writing a Haskell function that takes in a string and replaces any duplicate characters in the string with '_'. So far, I have this:

```
markDups :: [Char] -> [Char]
markDups = dupsHelp []
where dupsHelp c [] = c
      dupsHelp c (x:xs)
          | x `elem` c = dupsHelp c xs
          | otherwise = dupsHelp (c ++ [x]) xs
```

The code deletes the repeating characters.

Example : "Hello World" -> "Helo Wrd"

How would I modify this code to get "Hel_o W_r_d"? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s quite simple:

```
markDups :: [Char] -> [Char]
markDups = dupsHelp []
where dupsHelp c [] = c
      dupsHelp c (x:xs)
          | x `elem` c = dupsHelp (c ++ "_") xs
--                                ~~~~~~~~~~
          | otherwise = dupsHelp (c ++ [x]) xs
```

Instead of simply discarding `x`, you discard `x` and replace it with `'_'`.

You can also express this with a left fold:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

markDups = reverse . snd . foldl' go ([], [])
  where
  go (seen, acc) c =
    ( c : seen          -- Add character to seen duplicates for next step.
    , if c `elem` seen  -- If character is in duplicates:
      then '_' : acc    --   Add an underscore to result.
      else c : acc      --   Otherwise, just add the character.
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to store the already seen characters. You can simply remove all occurrences of your character from the rest of the string:

```
markDups :: [Char] -> [Char]
markDups []       = []
markDups ('_':xs) = '_' : markDups xs
markDups (x  :xs) = x   : markDups (map mark xs)
  where
    mark y = if x == y then '_' else y
```